# How can i report ViewsLifeTime for a page?

Tags: web-analytics

I want to know how many people visit the website. And i want to write this information to Excel. How can i do that in Sharepoint?

Comment: How about firing a search rest api query with keyword as "path:<url of the page>" and requesting value of ViewsLifeTime managed property?

Comment: Also you can generate such reports out of the box using site collection audit settings. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-A9920C97-38C0-44F2-8BCB-4CF1E2AE22D2

Answer (score 0):

which version of sharepoint are you using ? on prem or online ?

on prem has something called usage logs that can help you.

if you are using SP Online you'll have to use some third party technologies like google analytics and place a piece of code on your site that will store how much times the page has been visited